# On TypeORM, I am required to specify all relevant ColumnOptions?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am working on a scenario were database model is maintained by another team.

When describing the Entity on TypeORM for the application, do I need to repeat the database description within the `@Column` annotation?

For example, if a column is `nullable` on the database, do I need to specify `@Column({ nullable: true })` on the `@Entity`?
Does TypeORM infer missing `ColumnOptions` attributes from the database model?

I am concerned about 'repeating myself' when coding the entities. And that database model may diverge from the TypeORM model.

I understand that `ColumnOptions` are intended for generating automatically the datamodel/migration ddl script.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the basic model of how TypeORM defines database entities, then you must annotate every property in the class you want to be a column in the database.

> For example, if a column is nullable on the database, do I need to specify @Column({ nullable: true }) on the @Entity?

Do not forget, that typescript classes contains type declarations, which disappear when you compile them to js. There will be no property definitions in the end, so typescript wouldn't know if a column must be nullable.

> Does TypeORM infer missing `ColumnOptions` attributes from the database model?

Note, that usually databases have different (or often more) data types than we can describe in typescript (or javascript). Let's take an example with PostgreSQL: we can [define dates multiple ways in the database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html), but none of them resembles to the typescript (or javascript) counterpart: the Date object.

TypeORM can make guesses from property types (by using the `reflect-metadata` library), but **annotating everything would be the best practice**, because in that way, you'll get everything exactly, how you want.

> I am concerned about 'repeating myself' when coding the entities. And that database model may diverge from the TypeORM model.

That is a valid concern in this case, and fortunately TypeORM has a solution for separating types and model definitions. You can read more about it [here](https://typeorm.io/#/separating-entity-definition).

I hope it could help!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your detailed and objective explanation. Yesterday I was still wishfully thinking not having to repeat the model metadata within TS :-)

Comment: @csakbalint Just trying to understand the nuance more. I like the best practice of explicitly matching the schema but wouldn't it be just for context and not required? If I had a phone number field, for example, wouldn't it just be defined on the type as `phoneNumber: number` and the ColumnOptions of `@Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 10, nullable: false, unique: true })` would just be used in the event of synchronize being true?

Comment: It depends on the level of your desired validation in your application: if you want more strictness, use database-level validation. If you want to be flexible, because you haven't finalized your schema yet, then use schema-level validation.
I generic rule of thumb I use most of the time is, that I use schema-level validation everytime, except for identifiers, such as primary email, phone, id. In this case I use database-level validation.